# Is there an iOS benchmark program similar to the PC/Mac world?

Tags: ios, hardware, benchmarking

In the PC/Mac world we are used to having magazines and individuals running special software suits crafted to explore the limits of hardware and benchmark their performance in a variety of situations. There are OpenGL specific benchmarks, DirectX ones, CPU/GPU benchmarks, SMP benchmarks, etc, etc.

Does something similar exists for the iOS world? I'm not talking about Apple's usual "we are 3 times faster than ever!" reports that get repeated by mainstream media. I'm looking for software suites which for instance profile the amount of draw operations that can be done, the time it takes to unzip files from the flash memory, json/image processing on one core vs multiple cores, amount of time it takes to deplete the battery running at 100%, etc. Something like http://www.xbench.com/ but for iOS devices.

Also of interest would be knowing the performance comparison of the benchmark suite deployed on the same device but compiled against different SDK versions, so you can compare the performance of the SDK too and see if Apple is improving/worsening the overall performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's an iphone version of Geekbench http://itunes.apple.com/es/app/geekbench-2/id377657310?mt=8 (http://primatelabs.ca/geekbench/ on the web) unfortunately closed source, so I can't add my tests.

Comment: cant seem to locate it in the store.

Comment: That is a direct link, maybe not available in your country. Added http://primatelabs.ca/geekbench/ where it shows on their website.